# Mixing http and http2 under the same server on nginx

Tags: nginx, grpc

I'm trying to have a single server on nginx serving both http2 routes and traditional http1 routes, my problem is that I cannot get it to play nicely.

When I try to access my app on the subfolder, that runs on gunicorn+flask, I get a download file with some binary

How can I serve both?

```
    server {
        listen 80 http2;

        access_log /dev/stdout main;
        rewrite_log on;
        error_log /dev/stdout debug;

        location /some.Service {
            grpc_pass grpc://srvadd:10116;
        }

        location /password-reset {
            proxy_pass http://flask:8000;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you remove the gRPC endpoint, does the `proxy_pass` to Flask then work properly, or does the issue persist?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm getting the exact same issue and hard to find any relevant issue on the net...

Answer (score 1):

hm, serving both http and http2 traffic under the same nginx server should work. This is one example nginx.conf that works for us

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen 8443 http2;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      grpc_pass localhost:9090;
    }
  }
```

I am not entirely sure, but does port 80 work with http2? I think there might be some restriction on what port number you can use with http2?

another slightly more involved example

```
  server {
    listen [::]:$0;
    listen [::]:$1 http2;
    server_name localhost;
    location /grpc.gateway.testing.EchoService/ {
      grpc_pass localhost:$2;
      grpc_channel_reuse on;
      grpc_ssl $3;
      grpc_ssl_target_name_override $4;
      grpc_ssl_pem_root_certs "$5";
      grpc_ssl_pem_private_key "$6";
      grpc_ssl_pem_cert_chain "$7";
      grpc_client_liveness_detection_interval 10ms;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * always;
    }
  }
```